# How `shapeless.Cached` works?

Tags: scala, implicit, shapeless

Running the following code

```scala
import shapeless._

final case class Foo(s: String) { println("HELLO") }

object TestApp extends App {
  implicit def foo(implicit s: String): Foo = Foo(s)

  implicit val s : String = "123"

  implicitly[Foo]

  implicitly[Foo]

  val f1 = implicitly[Cached[Foo]].value
  val f2 = implicitly[Cached[Foo]].value
  println(f1 eq f2)
}
```

I would assume it displays 3 "HELLO" printed on screen, and the comparison result is `true`.

Instead, this is what I get,

```scala
HELLO
HELLO
HELLO
HELLO
false
```

Is my understanding wrong about the way to use `Cached` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`def` is evaluated as many times as it is called. But if you change implicit `def` by `val` you'll have one `HELLO` and `true`.

Difference between non-cached and cached implicit `val`s can be shown as follows (it's written in scaladoc):

```
trait TC[T] {
  def msg: String
}

object First {
  implicit val tc: TC[Int] = new TC[Int] {
    val msg = "first"
  }

  def print() = println(implicitly[TC[Int]].msg)

  def printCached() = println(Cached.implicitly[TC[Int]].msg)
}

object Second {
  implicit val tc: TC[Int] = new TC[Int] {
    val msg = "second"
  }

  def print() = println(implicitly[TC[Int]].msg)

  def printCached() = println(Cached.implicitly[TC[Int]].msg)
}

First.print()//first
Second.print()//second
First.printCached()//first
Second.printCached()//first
```

Comment: thank you now I get the actual purpose of creating `Cached`. Do you know if there exists a way to cache `def` based implicit ?

Comment: `def foo(implicit s: String): Foo = Foo(s)`
`implicit val foo1: Foo = foo`